# in ie 8 in the document mode,why element can jump to the end of line

Tags: html, internet-explorer

-------test code(test.html)------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:orange;">
<b onmousemove="tip(this);">A</b> <b>B</b> <b>C</b><!--tip:when mouse is at here the same trigger the function tip()//-->
<fieldset>
    <legend id="mouseDot" style="display:block;background-color:red;height:5px;width:200px;"></legend>
    <div style="background-color:white;" id="tipTxt">onload mouseDot(red line) width=200px</div>
</fieldset>

<script>
function tip(tag) {
    mouseDot.style.width = event.x + 'px';
    tipTxt.innerHTML = 'mouse is move at x=' + event.x + ';so mouseDot(red line) width= ' + event.x + 'px';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Test environment is IE 9 (view mode is any one, but **document mode is IE 8**);

when your mouse move at `A`,it can call `function tip()` is normal;
**but when move at `<!--tip:when mouse is at here the same trigger the function tip()//-->` ,why it call `function tip()` too?**

You can see what happens on my blog with some screenshots: http://hi.baidu.com/qidizi/blog/item/2322e1f7335b074e342acc46.html

**tip:***Blog post has been modified, it should be more clearly*

**why the `A` can jump to `<!--tip:when mouse is at here the same trigger the function tip()//-->`,Only 3 pixel sizes, only reacts to mouse events, click on the event is invalid ?**

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear. The screenshots also don't make things clearer. By the way, `<div>`s don't have `width` attributes.

Comment: i think now the question and the blog is clearer,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the way IE handles white space in this document mode.  If you move the fieldset tag up so that it is right next to the last  tag, the issue goes away.  Like this:

```
<b>C</b><fieldset>
```

Not a great solution, but it works when you see this quirkly behavior.  I have also used this trick when IE secretly inserts some mysterious vertical spacing when you aren't expecting it.

Comment: Yes, turn `<b>C</b>` into `<b>c` (new line start) `</b>` can be solved, strange behavior